# how to convert list of hex values into hex string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, hex

```
hex_list = ['0x1', '0x17', '0x20', '0x19', '0x9']
```

I need to convert the hex list values in to hex string as it is given below:

```
hexStr = '0117201909'
```

Can some one please let me know how to do it in Python?

Comment: Please do more research before posting next time. Please see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158289/why-is-the-how-to-move-the-turtle-in-logo-question-closed).

Comment: please do let me know where I made a mistake, I still have an issue of creating the questions on Stack overflow. It would be great what was wrong on this specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```
hex_list = ['0x1', '0x17', '0x20', '0x19', '0x9']

hexStr = ''.join(x[2:].zfill(2) for x in hex_list)

print(hexStr)
```

Output:

```
0117201909
```